# If $p$ is a limit point, does there exist some point q such that it is present in all neighbourhoods of $p$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits

> A point $p$ is a limit point of the set $E$ if *every* neighbourhood of $p $ contains a point $q \neq p$ such that $q \in E$.

Can we refer to a specific instance of q that exists within *all* neighbourhoods and use those within proofs? For example, could I disprove that p is a limit point if I can find that there doesn't exist a point such that it is present in  all neighbourhoods? I *feel* like this should be true but my intuition is frequently shown to be wrong in real analysis.

Could someone push me in the right direction to help formulate a proof/disproof?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the point $q$ depend on the neighborhood.

It's even worse than that, in most (interesting) topological spaces, there is no such $q$ that is present in **all** neighborhood of $p$

As a simple exemple, take a metric space. Suppose there is such a $q$. As $q \neq p$, $d(p,q) = \epsilon > 0$. But consider the neighborhood $B(p,\frac{\epsilon}{2})$ : it doesn't contain $q$

Comment: A more explicit example in $\mathbb{R}$: $1$ is a limit point of $(0,1)$, but the only point in all of the intervals $(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$ is $1$ itself.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true if the space is separated. The real line for example is separated.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space

Answer (score 1):

A Fréchet space can be defined in many (equivalent) ways. One of them is that any point is the intersection of its neighbourhoods.

So, in a Fréchet space, there can not be another point in every neighbourhood of a point $p$.

Spaces that are not Fréchet spaces are quite pathological. For example, a sequence can have more than one limit. If some point $q$ is in every neighbourhood of $p$ then the constant sequence
$$(p,p,p\ldots)$$
converges to $p$, but also converges to $q$.

Comment: This is also called a $T_1$ space to avoid confusion with the Fréchet space in Functional Analysis.